# Justified Text in ScrollView Android Studio

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make a TextView justified in android the TextViews are in a ScrollView in a LinearLayout.

Ive seen online that I may need to switch to a WebView to make it work. 
But those posts seem a little outdated and maybe android implemented something new since then

Also, I need to be able to zoom in the ScrollView as well if anyone knows if thats possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to justify text in android.you can use HTML tags on textview.setText();

```
 <p align="left|right|center|justify">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

But center justification you can use attribute- gravity

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="paragraph"
    android:gravity="center"
   />
```

you layout_width should be match_parent to obtain a correct result.

Comment: Hey, I tried to do something like this, it did not end up working. `String htmltext = " <p align=\"justify\">"+ secondBeracha.getText() + "</p>";


        secondBeracha.setText(Html.fromHtml( htmltext ));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use library for that.
https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Comment: Hey I am pretty new to android, and coding. Can you maybe explain how I would implement the githun repo into my code? Thanks

Comment: Hey I finally got it to work! But for some reason, the text is a bit off. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666058/justified-text-with-rtl-using-bluejamesbond-textjustify-android is it possible for you to take a look? Thanks